# .htaccess 301 dynamic redirect matching database

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have incoming url http://www.example.com/index.html?id=1234

I have database WORDS with 2 columns: 'id' and 'url'

I need to 301 redirect matching the id parameter in url (1234) to corresponding URL, such as:

http:// www.example.com/index.html?id=1234 becomes
http:// www.redirectedurl.com

I tried something similar as what is explained [here](http://www.seobook.com/archives/001714.shtml)
I think the correct way is having a simple .htaccess code that uses a php file to match ids with urls in database but i don't know where to start.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: just use php. first get your url from database by `$_GET['id']` then redirect to the relative url. `header('Location:'.$url);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    //Check if GET value is set
    if(isset($_GET["id"]){

        //Retrieve values from database
        $db = new PDO(/* connect to your database here */);
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `url` FROM `table` WHERE `id`=? LIMIT 1");

        //If the statement doesn't execute
        if(!$stmt->execute(array(trim($_GET["id"])))) exit("Could not connect to database!");

        //If there are no rows returned
        if($stmt->rowCount()<1) exit("Could not find ID!");

        //Data is correct - redirect the user!
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $url = $row["url"];
        header("Location: ".$url);
        exit;            
    } else {
        echo "No ID set!";
    }
```

Comment: `.htaccess` is good for making URLs look prettier, e.g. *`yoursite.com/index.php?id=1234`* becomes *`yoursite.com/1234`*, for example. However, for your purposes, `.htaccess` won't be useful as it can't communicate with a database - and can't affect URLs on other sites, only your own.